# How to get filterToolbar value in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to get `filterToolbar` value in jqgrid.
But I don't know how to get it.

As shown below

I want to get

```
PRODUCTID : ABC

MODELNAME : 123ZXYZ
```

How can I get it?

Versions:

- jqGrid  5.1.1
- PHP Version 5.2.6

[example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO7Zs.jpg)

Comment: Which jqGrid PHP is used and which version?

Comment: I use jqGrid  5.1.1 PHP Version 5.2.6

Comment: Sorry... Tony.
I should not use jqGrid PHP.
I use Demo like that
http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to get the values server side, please, look at Guriddo documentation [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#posting-when-searching). You will see what values are posted to the server.

Additionally to this in tool bar searching all input fields are constructed with prefix **gs_** + idPrefix parameter + the name from colModel.  If the name in colModel is field1 and no idPrefix is set, then you can get the value with javascript like

```
$("#gs_field1").val()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Your example is what I need